# How to load Power Apps Portal list dynamically via Javascript

Tags: javascript, powerapps-portal

I know that there is a loaded event for lists in PAP that can be fetched with JS,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".entity-grid.subgrid").on("loaded", function () {
        //do something with list rows    
    });
});
```

but is it also possible to reload the list dynamically with javascript? (Sorry if this question is totally out of scope for PAP, I am a beginner.)

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

It is possible! You need to first enable APIs on the entity you wish to load by using [Site Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/portals/web-api-overview#site-settings-for-web-api), then call the code to load the data within your function. This [code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/portals/web-api-perform-operations#web-api-ajax-samples) should help you get started, and this [step by step example](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/portals/web-api-perform-operations#example) will help you get familiar with the concepts.

I hope this helps?!